# Vuex.js sidebar

Tags: vuex, sidebar

How can using Vuex store action and mutation to implement this sidebar? And need by adding a close button in element aside.

```
<div id="example-1">
  <button @click="show = !show">{{btnText}}</button>
  <transition name="slide">
    <aside v-show="show">hello</aside>
  </transition>
</div>

<style>
.slide-enter-active {
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
.slide-leave-active {
    transition: all .1s ease;
}
.slide-enter, .slide-leave-active {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
</style>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    show: false
  },
    computed: {
        btnText: function() {
            if(this.show) {
                return '✕'
            }
                return '☰'
     }
    }
})
<script>
```

https://codepen.io/pershay/pen/Pxgqwd

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Vuex for this functionality you will want 3 things

1. mutation
2. getter
3. state

the `state` of the side bar will be controlled by a `getter` which can be changed by a `mutation`

Below is a basic working example of toggling a sidebar with vuex.

**Note it is not using getter, if you don't understand how those work I can go into more  detail**

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boldstar/0movugab/)

**Below is using a toggle inside aside component with transition effect.**

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boldstar/0movugab/)

Here is Vue documentation for transitions [Vue Transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

Comment: Thank you! But I really don’t understand how I can hide the SlideBar now by click a button in aside area and how to apply transition slide effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/tcgm75vp/1/

Comment: @SvetaPershay, please see my updated answer. I added jsfiddle for button inside aside component and transition